# mqueue.h not found

Tags: c, linux, compilation, header-files

In one of my application, I am using "mqueue.h". I was able to compile and execute it. But one of our customer to whom I released the code, is complaining something like

*** mqueue.h is not found ***

He has not attached the exact error message though. In my linux PC, it is available in /usr/include. Can anyone guess any reason why the customer is not able to find the file?

Apologies for asking such trivial question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe he doesn't have the libc6-dev package installed?

- Debian: [libc6-dev](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libc6-dev)
- Ubuntu: [libc6-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc6-dev)
- Redhat, Centos, and other RPM based distros: [glibc-headers](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/3/search/glibc-headers)
- Suse: [glibc-devel](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&srodzaj=3&search=glibc-devel&dist%5B%5D=46&dist%5B%5D=67&dist%5B%5D=23)

Answer (score 7):

What @Stobor did not tell you is that '`<mqueue.h>`' is a standard header in [POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) (or, at least, the Single Unix Specification), and therefore most Unix-like platforms would be expected to provide it if the development system is installed.  If the development system is not installed, then the headers are usually missing.

Once upon a long time ago, the development system was always released with Unix.  Then it was made optional (originally, a paid-for optional part).  Then the Open Source movement made it optional but free.  The ability to develop software for a system significantly influences the uptake of a system.  That's why companies go to such lengths to make the SDK for their systems widely available.